# How do I keep the same UID among many servers?

Tags: linux, permissions, rsync, user, uid

I have many servers with `LDAP` which mantain the users `UID` the same among the servers, but how can I change and keep the same UID for local users ?

For example, the user `tomcat`, when someone create an script that do install a `tomcat`, `apache` or another software and with it has the user `tomcat` for it, right ?
But when someone makes a `rsync` of some files, keeping the permissions, in the other server cames with the wrong permissions. I would like to avoid that. How can I do that ?

Comment: At least for rsync, there is no need to have the same UID.  If the user is on both ends, rsync will make the ownership correct (the option --numeric-ids turns OFF this behaviour).

Comment: Sure, but if the user, local users, has different UID in both servers, the problem persist.